How to remove Tailwind CSS safely from my Next.js project?
I started my Next.js project using this template, and it came with Tailwind CSS configured by default. I used it for a while, then started using Material UI. Now I'm sure I don't need Tailwind anymore, and want to remove it.
When I do (npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer, remove all config files) I get some issues. My next/font and next/image don't show properly. Do Next.js components and utilites requiere Tailwind?

I had a similar situation, and was able to do so by following these steps.

Remove all Tailwind packages with npm uninstall ...
Had to do this for tailwindcss, tailwindcss-animate and tailwind-merge
Delete tailwind.config.ts from the project
Remove the tailwind section from components.json
Optionally, run npm run build, just to catch any remaining issues early

Seems to have worked like a charm, fingers crossed.
